# replacing "view cart" button with "proceed to checkout" button upon adding a product to cart

Tags: notifications, woocommerce, customization

After product page reloads upon adding the product to cart, a notification appears on top saying "product was added to cart" followed by a "view cart" button.

However after product gets added to cart I want to direct customers to checkout page (where I'll add cart page functionality), not cart page. How can I replace the notification's link to cart with a link to checkout page?

`wc_add_to_cart_message()` function (in `includes/wc-cart-functions.php`) seems to generate this particular notification, should I override this function? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```
function rei_wc_add_to_cart_message( $message, $product_id ) {
    $titles = array();

    if ( is_array( $product_id ) ) {
        foreach ( $product_id as $id ) {
            $titles[] = get_the_title( $id );
        }
    } else {
        $titles[] = get_the_title( $product_id );
    }

    $titles     = array_filter( $titles );
    $added_text = sprintf( _n( '%s has been added to your cart.', '%s have been added to your cart.', sizeof( $titles ), 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );

    // Output success messages
    if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) ) {
        $return_to = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url() );
        $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( $return_to ), esc_html__( 'Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
    } else {
        $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ) ), esc_html__( 'Proceed to Checkout', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
    }

    return $message;
}
add_filter('wc_add_to_cart_message','rei_wc_add_to_cart_message',10,2);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks @Reigel. One question though for future similar problems: how can I discover myself the existence of hooks such as the 'wc_add_to_cart_message' one?

Comment: if you know how to search texts on files within folder, you could just search  the word you are looking for.. I've used notepad++ to search woocommerce folder for "view cart".

Comment: Thanks, I just did and found 6 instances but none of them relates to the 'wc_add_to_cart_message' hook!

Comment: there's 1 in `wc-cart-functions.php`

Comment: Spotted it, I'll try to follow the same method next time I come across a similar problem. Thanks again!